# What is this syntax, parentheses around variable/property names at declaration site?

Tags: kotlin

```
val (_,time) = time { Thread.sleep(1000) }
```

I see the Left Hand Side (LHS) has a val, so its declaring a variable. LHS also has some kind of a function syntax which does not look like a lambda declaration. What is `(_,time)`? Don’t you have to give a type to the time on the LHS? I understand the RHS perfectly well: it is a function which accepts a lambda as parameter and is named ‘time’. [Original code](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/what-is-this-syntax/8278?u=araghuraman1)

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html

Comment: You should [format your code block](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361). Personally I would not recommend using bold, just mention it below like you already did is fine.

Comment: Apparently some function time takes lambda as a parameter and returns two values, one of them is not used and replaces with `_`

Comment: Thanks to your replies!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The left hand side is called [**destructuring**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html).

If you try to assign an instance of a data class (or any `class` which has `componentN` functions) to a variable you can desturcture it. This means that you can assign its internals to variables. The `_` syntax indicates that you don't care about the first item.

Example:

```
class Foo(val first: String, val second: String) {

    operator fun component1() = first

    operator fun component2() = second
}
```

Usage:

```
val (first, second) = Foo("first", "second")
```

If you use `data class`es you don't need to create the `componentN` functions, they are generated for you.

Equivalent `data class`:

```
data class Foo(val first: String, val second: String)
```

Comment: Egads. Another example of kotlin preferring conciseness and unnecessary features over clarity. I'd rather have ten lines of code that's easy to understand than one line of cryptic inscrutable code that does the same thing. Clarity is king.

Comment: For example, see the sample code on TriStateCheckbox. WTF is that doing? https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#tristatecheckbox